# Remove end character from BrightScript string

Tags: brightscript

I'm using this command to extract some number after ?text=;
re = CreateObject ("roRegex", ".*?text=([^,]+),(.*)", "s")

and I get back what I want but with an extra character at the end; 1234"

What I want is only the 1234

How can I now remove the " at the end of this? Can I use Trim() or split? not sure how to. Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out my own answer : https://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=97602#p544884

Answer (score 0):

Use `Replace` function from ifStringOps (https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/ifStringOps)

> Replace(from As String, to As String) As String

```
result = "1234" + Chr(34) ' 1234"
result = result.Replace(Chr(34), "")
```

Comment: bad idea. to see why, try `? ("lemme ""quote"" that""").replace(chr(34), "")`

Answer (score -1):

The same was recently covered in 
https://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=97602#p544884